# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR', while the same code worked in a guide

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to roll up multiple rows into one with FOR XML PATH. I'm not sure why I got the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'"

I was following this guide: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

```
SELECT
    movie.name, movie.date, movie.filelocation, 
    movie.imdb, movie.description,
    STUFF ((SELECT ';' + genre.name 
            FROM genre
            WHERE genre.id = mov_genr.gen_id 
              AND movie.id = mov_genr.mov_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') [genres]
FROM 
    movie
FULL JOIN 
    mov_genr on movie.id = mov_genr.mov_id
FULL JOIN 
    genre on mov_genr.gen_id = genre.id
```

I have 3 tables, `movie` with a bunch of movies, `mov_genr` which is a table that connects movies with genres, and `genre` table, which contains the genres.

I want a query that shows me all the movies and all the genres for those movies but don't duplicate the movie rows and just shows the genres as 1 connected string.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma before `STUFF`:

```
Select movie.name,movie.date,movie.filelocation, movie.imdb, movie.description, -- here

    STUFF ((SELECT ';' + genre.name FROM genre
    WHERE genre.id = mov_genr.gen_id AND movie.id = mov_genr.mov_id
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1,'') [genres]

FROM movie
FULL JOIN mov_genr on movie.id = mov_genr.mov_id
FULL JOIN genre on mov_genr.gen_id = genre.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.  I think you want:

```
Select m.*,
       STUFF( (SELECT ';' + genre.name
               FROM mov_genr mg JOIN
                    genre g
                    ON g.id = mg.gen_id 
               WHERE m.id = mg.mov_id
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as genres
FROM movie m;
```

One problem is a missing comma.

But you have logic problems as well.  You want want row per movie (presumably), so `join`s are not appropriate in the outer query.

Further `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed with a well-designed data model.

Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.